# Blazor WASM (Hosted) + Azure AD B2C Fails To Redirect To Login Page When Published

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

Have a .Net 6 Blazor Hosted WASM app configured to use Azure B2C, the app requires authentication for every page except the Authentication page which allows anonymous.

Running locally it works, redirecting the user to B2C to authenticate. However when published to Windows Web App on Azure it loads, then redirects to {site}/authentication/login-failed, making no attempt to redirect.

There is nothing in the logs to indicate an issue (either server or browser), and suspect it is something it has done in the build (perhaps trimming). However tried a fews (possibly unrelated) suggestions from the web and cannot get it working.

Comment: Did you verified that redirect URI iendpoint set in AD B2C is same as where your application is hosted,  I have a feeling that it's still local host there

Answer (score 1):

For those that have this problem, can follow the steps outlined here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38082

Make sure you delete the bin and obj files, clean and restart otherwise get some checksum issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your .csproj file to prevent the trimming of the authentication package when publishing!

```
<ItemGroup>   <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" />  </ItemGroup>
```

After this delete the obj and bin folders!

here is more information on this issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33312

[Blazor WASM Net 6 Preview 4 Azure AD - There was an error trying to log you in: 'Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805062/blazor-wasm-net-6-preview-4-azure-ad-there-was-an-error-trying-to-log-you-in?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

For those that end up here with wasm .net 8 in Feb 2024, the following worked for me. Note, this is a different include statement to the one that worked for .net 7 when this issue was initially raised and resolved:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/49956

add the following to csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Ensure that you clean the bin/obj files if you're not using a external build pipeline.