# AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption - Published on Azure

Tags: azure, blazor, single-sign-on, webassembly, azure-ad-msal

I like to get MSAL Authentication running when i hosted my app on Azure.
I get the folowing screen when i publish my Blazor WASM App on Azure as WebApp.

Error screen

[image: 1]

If i debug with localhost all works like a charme and i am logged in and i will be redirect to my app, but if i publish my app to azure it wont work.

I have tried to add the redirect url the "Web" instead of "SPA" but then i will instantly forwarded to /authentication/login-failed in my app.

If i use "Spa" in the Manifest i will be redirected to Microsoft Login. I fill my data and get the same Screen shown above.

I use .Net 6 and the following NuGet Package:

NuGet Package

[image: 2]

Please can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Greets Sascha

Comment: can you please check what error you are getting after trying with platform to "web"

Comment: Hallo
If i set platform to web and try to login with new inkognito Tag in the Browser i get no Error, the app will instanstly redirect to ....../authentication/login-failed

I use the "RemoteAuthenticatorView" Component, and also in the Console from the Browser are no errors.

How o can see any erros with these component?

Thanks
Br
Sascha

Comment: OK, now i get an error when i use the buildin RenderFragment of the "RemoteAuthenticatorView" Component. Error: There was an error trying to log you in: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')'

Comment: I try the workaround from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805062/blazor-wasm-net-6-preview-4-azure-ad-there-was-an-error-trying-to-log-you-in
But now I get an error , but only at the redirect uri, not on UI.

authentication/login-failed?message=9002326%20-%20%5B2022-08-20%2006%3A40%3A04Z%5D%3A%20AADSTS9002326%3A%20Cross-origin%20token%20redemption%20is%20permitted%20only%20for%20the%20%27Single-Page%20Application%27%20client-type.%20Request%20origin....

Comment: Have you checked if manifest and appregistration redirect url have different platforms given ..or both given (spa and web). If thats the case make sure only one platform is given.ex: manifest and  redirect url in app registration Only with *SPA*

Comment: OK, now i get back to SPA and it runs. I think the workaround with the AssemblyTrimming was the goal. Thanks to all for try to help me

Answer (score 1):

Indeed in some cases ,you must add the redirect URLs under **Web** platform and not  SPA (single page application.)

Also try changing  replyUrlsWithType to web in the manifest in azure
portal.

```
"replyUrlsWithType": [ 
        {
        "url": "https://local.com ",
        "type":"web"
         } 
         ],
```

[image]

- If the type **web** is causing the error, try changing to SPA in the similar
  way.

Please also check [Redirect URI (reply URL) restrictions - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).

> **Note**:But please try to delete the url and clear the cache before updating the new one with new url type based on the application.

Comment: Hy
I have tried this, see my comment above, but i will instantly redirekt to "login-failed" page. If i use "Web" instead of "Spa" the app wont to show me the Login-View.

Thanks
Greets
Sascha