# Blazor WASM error when user is not authenticated: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Tags: azure, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Webassembly app on .NET 6 deployed to Azure Blob Storage (static website).
It uses Azure Active Directory for authentication.

Locally authentication works fine: when I am not authenticated it redirects to a Microsoft login page.

But when a not authenticated user is trying to open the deployed app, it does not redirect to the login page, but displays this error:

**There was an error trying to log you in: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')')**

All Nuget packages are the most recent.
The code is the standard Blazor template code.

This might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805062/blazor-wasm-net-6-preview-4-azure-ad-there-was-an-error-trying-to-log-you-in) question, but I tried everything mentioned in answers and replies there, to no avail.

Comment: This is 100% a duplicate of the other question. Please show us your project file settings. Also did you delete all bin and obj folders from the solution and delete all the files in destination folder on the server before publishing again?

Comment: Seriously man, is this some kind of a joke to you? I said I did everything in the answers and replies. Then on your next comment you literally link to the question I referred to and ask whether it answers my question.

Comment: @Dabriel The second comment was added automatically because he flagged your question as duplicate, accordingly to the first comment.

Comment: @Dabriel: I've retracted my close vote because you posted a solution and it may help future visitors. My main reason for marking it as a duplicate was you said `I tried everything` but we have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by targeting .NET 7.0 RC2, per https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38082

There was nothing that could resolve this issue for my project while targeting .NET 6.0, I did everything I could find on Stackoverflow and Github